# COUNT with two columns each with its own AS value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to `COUNT` two different values in my query, the thing is I need to assign two different AS values because the values are separate.

I have tried adding + as well as `AND` to get this to work. I am unsure of what else to do, and again I cannot have `friend_one` and `friend_two` added together.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(friend_one) AS pending_count + COUNT(friend_two) AS requests_sent
FROM friends
WHERE friend_one OR friend_two = ?
AND status = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz try something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(friend_one = $myID) AS pending_count,
   SUM(friend_two = $myID) AS pending_count
FROM friends
WHERE friend_one = $myID
   OR friend_two = $myID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
 SELECT *, (COUNT(friend_one) + COUNT(friend_two)) AS pending_count_And_requests_sent
FROM friends
WHERE friend_one OR friend_two = ?
AND status = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need subquery to access count columns and add them

```
SELECT *,pending_count1 + pending_count2 As request_sent
FROM
(
SELECT *, COUNT(friend_one) AS pending_count1 , COUNT(friend_two) AS pending_count2
FROM friends
WHERE friend_one OR friend_two = ?
AND status = ?
) As Tmp
```

This gives all columns from friends table and count of freind ane and freind 2 and thier sum as request_sent